# Xcode Healthkit authorized function error when migrate to Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The following function was working in Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.*, after migrate to Xcode 8  and Swift 3.0 I got the following error when I try to compile

> cannot call value of non-function type `((Bool, _ error:NSError?) ->
>   Void)!`

```
     func authorizeHealthKit(_ completion: ((_ success:Bool, _ error:NSError?) -> Void)!) {
            healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
            let typesSet:Set<HKSampleType> = [
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!,
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.respiratoryRate)!,
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic)!,
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic)!, 
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!, 
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
                    HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation)!]


                healthKitStore?.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesSet, read: typesSet, completion: { (boolVal, error) in
                    completion(success: boolVal, error: error)   //<-- compile error here
            })
     }
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Try making your completion handler optional as below:

completion?(success: boolVal, error: error)

Also to note from Apple API documentation:

Important
An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access or it will crash. To access and update HealthKit data specifically, it must include the NSHealthShareUsageDescription and NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription keys, respectively.

Hope this helps.